# maven-replacer-plugin gives weirdly expanded output

Tags: java, maven

I am using the maven-replacer-plugin together with the Maven build system to expand a template file to include the project's artifactId and version, but somehow seems to go wrong using the plugin, but I cannot figure out why as I seem to have a correct definition:

Fragment from my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <file>cardshifter-server.template.policy</file>
                <outputFile>${project.parent.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.policy</outputFile>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>[artifactId]</token>
                        <value>${project.artifactId}</value>
                    </replacement>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>[version]</token>
                        <value>${project.version}</value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Running on the following cardshifter-server.template.policy:

```
grant codeBase "file:./[artifactId]-[version].jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant {
    //mod permissions
};
```

with artifactId = cardshifter-server and version = 0.4-SNAPSHOT gives me the following output:

```
gca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT ca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTBca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT "ca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTl0.4-SNAPSHOT:./[ca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT]-[0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT].jca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT" {
    p0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTmca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT jca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT.0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTuca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTy.AllP0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTmca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT;
};

gca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT {
    //m0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT p0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTmca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOTca0.4-SNAPSHOTd0.4-SNAPSHOTh0.4-SNAPSHOTft0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT-0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT0.4-SNAPSHOT
};
```

Can anyone explain me what happened?

Comment: Not experienced with the replacer plugin, however I've run into issues with other similar things when multiple sets of replacement identifiers are on the same line.  Can you change the delimiters for one of them, e.g. @version@, and see if that works?

Comment: @user944849 That actually was the issue, seems like I did not read the documentation well enough.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not experienced with the replacer plugin, however I've run into issues with other similar things when multiple sets of replacement identifiers are on the same line. Try changing the delimiters for one of them, e.g. @version@, and see if that works.